# Does Libgdx have an implementation of display lists?

Tags: java, opengl, libgdx

I'm stuck developing on an old computer with OpenGL 1.1 only.  As such i'm grateful I can use ImmediateMode10 etc, but I don't see a way for me to create display lists in Libgdx.  I've searched for glGenList but I don't see it anywhere in the code.  Am I missing something simple?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LibGDX uses the OpenGL "ES" subset that was developed for mobile devices.  It maps that to standard OpenGL on the desktop, but in general complete OpenGL isn't available through libGDX.  Display lists are one of the [things that were removed from OpenGL to create OpenGL ES 1.0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL_ES#OpenGL.C2.A0ES.C2.A01.0).

If you are only interested in the OpenGL Java bindings on the desktop, and want more complete OpenGL support, the [LWJGL](http://www.lwjgl.org/) library [supports display lists](http://schabby.de/display-lists/).

Comment: Doh.  Sounds like I need a new cheap laptop.  Thanks.